# Defining $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

This question is based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684610/734160) post. Here is the question:

> At $x=0$ , $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has ____? (Options are *maxima*, *minima*, *point of inflection*, *dicontinuity*)

I have failed to draw a plausible conclusion from what the answers say and the chat discussion(very interesting) there.

Here are some of the points that I wish to clarify:

**1)** Is it relevant to talk about continuity at a point where a function isn't even defined(first, third answers **( * , *** )**)?

**2)** How can one *extend the domain* of the function to remove this *discontinuity*

**3)** The original question does not talk about extending the domain of the function, so is answer 2 **( ** )** valid?

---

Pictures of answers for reference:

**(*)**[image]

**( ** )**[image]

**( *** )**[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not well posed since the function is not defined at $x=0$ and therefore it is meaningless ask for continuity for a point out of its natural domain.

If we define $f(0)=0$ then the new function has a [removable discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity) since we can redefine $f(0)=1$ and this final new function has a maximum at that point.

Refer also to the related

- [Can a continuous function have discontinuities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2829882/505767)

Comment: Agreed, the question has been phrased poorly. Just to be clear, the function has a removable discontinuity now that the condition $f(0)=0$ is added right?(and not previously)

Comment: @DatBoi Yes, otherwise it is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, we can extend $f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ to a continuous function by defining
$$\bar{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x), &x\ne 0\\
1, &x=0
\end{cases}.$$  We often call $\bar{f}$ the *continuous extension* of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Here, then, we have that $\bar{f}$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, so one only needs show that $\bar{f}$ is also continuous at $x = 0$.